# Activity goes below status bar when soft keyboard opened

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I am developing android custom keyboard and faced this problem. I am using candidates view to show suggestions. But in some cases when I am trying to use keyboard in applications Layout is going under status bar.
I have attached two images of problem. In both screenshots with red rectangle I have marked problem and with green rectangle Keyboard layout.
I have done research about this and find that it can be caused if Candidate view is not created in right way, but I have implemented candidate view as shown in examples.[This is an Image from Facebook messenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUFBF.png)
[In this image keyboard is overlapping messengers edit text layout too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uW7P.png)

Here are my code snippets from SoftKeyboard where i am creating candidates view.`

```
@Override public View onCreateCandidatesView() {
    mCandidateView = new CandidateView(this);
    mCandidateView.setService(this);
    mCandidateView.setOnTranslitModeChangedListener(this);
    return mCandidateView;
}`
```

my keyboard xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.innorise.kitkeysarmenian.LatinKeyboardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/keyboard"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:keyTextSize="18dp"
android:keyTextColor="#000"
android:background="@color/keyboardBackground"
android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview"
android:popupLayout="@layout/keyboard_popup_layout"
android:drawingCacheQuality="high">
```

and here is my candidates view xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/candidatesList"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/candidateSwitch"/>
    <TextView
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Translit is off."
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/translitModeisOff"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/candidateSwitch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />
    <com.rm.rmswitch.RMSwitch
    android:id="@+id/candidateSwitch"
    app:switchDesign="slim"
    app:switchBkgCheckedColor="#4ed736"
    app:switchBkgNotCheckedColor="#cccccc"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:switchToggleCheckedColor="#aca2a2"
    app:switchToggleNotCheckedColor="#aca2a2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your manifest :

```
       <activity
          android:name="activity.name"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"/>
```

Comment: I am developing keyboard and problem is called by keyboard I can not add this statement to applications where I am using keyboard, and adding this to keyboard's manifest didn't help.